# Python Script (PyQt5 GUI Component) Running in Docker Container and Not Connecting to Display

Tags: python, docker, user-interface, dockerfile, pyqt5

I have a Python script that is using a PyQt5 GUI to set different variables based off of the user's input for querying a database. I have the container in Docker and everything is fine but when I run the container with `docker run surefire_loader` it bombs out with this error: `QStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set, defaulting to '/tmp/runtime-root' qt.qpa.screen: QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display Could not connect to any X display.`

My Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM python:3.6

ADD salesforce_extract_dict.py /
ADD config.py /
ADD requirements.txt /

RUN apt-get update && apt-get -qq install libgl1-mesa-glx
RUN pip install --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host 
files.pythonhosted.org -r requirements.txt

CMD [ "python", "./salesforce_extract_dict.py" ]
```

I am executing this on a Mac at the moment but I am looking to move it over to a Windows PC for production - if this info helps at all.

What could be the particular issue and how can I get the GUI to connect to my local machine's display?

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: @Akhilesh I never did find a solution, unfortunately.